# Vertical alignment of Raphael canvas broken in Twitter bootstrap tab

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, raphael, angular-ui

I just filed a [bug](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/14209) for Twitter bootstrap tab element.

I am asking here to see if somebody has ideas for a workaround until this bug is fixed.

**The problem:**

The layout in the tabs seems to behave different whether the tab is active or hidden initially. When drawing SVG elements (in this case, with Raphael.js), the vertical alignment is different, depending on the initial tab state (active or not).

Here is a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/andimeier/gxEff/) demonstrating the issue.

**Explanation:** the following Raphael instructions should draw a text horizontally and vertically centered into a circle (should look like a Billard ball).

```
paper.circle(13, 13, 10.5);
paper.text(13, 13, "10");
```

This works in many cases, but if you draw the same on a canvas in an inactive bootstrap tab and then switch to it, you can see that here the alignment is broken. See my fiddle.

Maybe there's a quick workaround? Can I "reset" the viewport in the hidden tab somehow?

BTW: I stumbled across this problem using angular-ui, that's why this question is tagged with angular as well. But the problem seems to lie within Bootstrap.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my description of how I worked around this issue.

cvrebert's reply to my bug report:

> The usual solution when there are problems rendering hidden things is
>   to not render stuff in hidden tabs on page load, and instead hook into
>   the `shown` tab event and do the rendering then.

In the following explanation, notice that I use AngularJS and the `angular-ui-bootstrap` module, not the "native" Twitter bootstrap one.

So I did as cvrebert suggested:

- added `select` handler to the tab containing the Raphael SVG canvas
- in the corresponding controller, on `select` fired, I started drawing - and not earlier